# Using await is not waiting for a Promise to resolve, can you please tell me why I'm facing this behavior?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I have got a function like this,

```
 const getCurrentDetails= async () => {
    const currentDateTime = new Date(moment('00:00','HH:mm')
                                    .tz('America/New_York')
                                    .toISOString());
    const currentDateDetail = await getDetailsForTimestamp(currentDateTime);
    console.log("currentDateDetail: ",currentDateDetail)  //prints PromiseProvider {}
  if(currentDateDetail){
  //do some stuff if details present
   }
}
```

Even though I'm using **await** to **resolve the promise before going to the next step**, but still it **logs PromiseProvider {} in the next step** and the following condition check fails to validate properly.

Note that the same function works fine sometimes, but not consistent as I face the above-mentioned behavior many times, I'm using **node 16**, and here's the getDetailsForTimestamp function.

```
const getDetailsForTimestamp = async (currentTimeStamp) => {
      const { db } = await database.getDb(process.env.DB_NAME);
      if (db) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          db.collection(process.env.COLLECTION_NAME)
            .findOne({ updatedAt: { $gte: currentTimeStamp } })
            .then((res) => {
              resolve(res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
        });
      }
    };
```

Comment: could you add `console.log(res)` above this line `resolve(res);`? what does it print? maybe your `res` is a promise

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Comment: to be honest, I'm surprised the code runs at all since you are trying to use `await` in a function that **isn't** `async` - or am I missing something?

Comment: It does not run. Also this `function getCurrentDetails()=>{` arrow-non-arrow-function is syntactically incorrect

Comment: clearly the issue is something else entirely :p the REAL code is probably doing things wrong in a different way

Comment: Hi @Bravo and FZs, thanks for responding. It was a typing mistake, I've updated the correct code in the question. I still face the issue with syntactically correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use

```
async await instead of Promise
```

Try with replacing your method "getDeatilsForTimestamp" with this:

```
const getDetailsForTimestamp = async currentTimeStamp => {
const { db } = await database.getDb(process.env.DB_NAME);
if (db) {
 try {
   return await db
    .collection(process.env.COLLECTION_NAME)
    .findOne({ updatedAt: { $gte: currentTimeStamp } });
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: why do so many people `return await somethingThatReturnsAPromise` .... just `return somethingThatReturnsAPromise` and get on with your life :p

Comment: and if you want to concentrate on the function that could not cause the issue - I'd write it like `const getDetailsForTimestamp = async($gte) => (await database.getDb(process.env.DB_NAME))?.collection(process.env.COLLECTION_NAME).findOne({updatedAt: {$gte}});` because I'm an idiot that likes one liners :p